# phpDocumentator additional project description

Tags: phpdoc

How can I add a project description in phpDocumentor (version 3.3.1) that is unrelated to the code, such as describing the purpose of the project? I am aware of the existence of the following functionality: https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/hand-written-docs/index.html#guides, but I do not know how to use it to accomplish my goal.